Understanding fails in Dymola simulateMultiResultsModel
I use Dymola's simulateMultiResultsModel function to simulate multiple sets of parameters as part of a parameter estimation process (in Python). However, it appears that if simulation of one parameter set fails, all simulations fail, and I can't receive the results for all other parameter sets. Is it possible to get the results of the non-failing parameter sets?

That requires adding the special variable "terminal" as output.
Consider:
model U
  parameter Real p=1;
  Real x;
equation 
  assert(p>0, "Required");
  der(x)=1-p*x;
end U;

To simulate and get results use:
simulateMultiResultsModel("U",initialNames={"p"},initialValues=[1;2;-1;3],numberOfIntervals=2,resultNames={"x","terminal"})

The failing results have 0 as result for terminal (after the simulation failed).
This is documented in the Dymola User's Manual under simulateMultiExtendedModel (page 970 for Dymola 2023x Refresh 1; page 1002 for Dymola 2025x).

This works for me, but when I use many parameter sets, the behavior falls back to the original. This appears to happen approximately when the number of parameter sets surpasses the number of available CPUs, and multIn/-Out contains values/results for both failing and non-failing parameter sets. In this case, the following error is issued:
Incorrect data-length for file "multOut1.csv" should be 6 * 2=12, but was 6

Submit a bug report to Dassault Systèmes.
